# Cavegame.io autominer in Python keeps sending None error

Tags: python, automation

This is my code:
import time
import pyautogui as pt

time.sleep(4)

def GoToNearestIron():

```
coord = pt.locateOnScreen("image/Iron.png")
coords = [coord]
print(coords)
```

GoToNearestIron

Here are my assets:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mainqr_46aPhlhIqFJVHIAVjb2r8c2dqYBAMo-64cT4/edit?usp=sharing

My code keeps returning [none]
If anyone could help me I would be very thankful!

Comment: Just `None` or `ImageNotFoundException`?

Comment: run the program and bring the image on the screen.

Comment: @Tanay I already did that and still returns it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and tell me if it works:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    coord = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image/Iron.png")
    coords = [coord]
    print(coords)
    if coord != None:
        break
```

Comment: No sorry I even tried making the image into 62 by 62 so it didnt detect any unwanted pixels but still nothing.

Comment: You should check if the image on screen is same size and if it is and program still returns none, then refer to this [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/kqbgvd/error_using_confidence_in_pyautogui/)